# Searching the closest value in other column

Tags: r, time-series

Suppose we have a data frame of two columns

```
 X    Y 
 10  14 
 12  16   
 14  17  
 15  19   
 21  19
```

The first element of Y that is 14, the nearest value (or same) to it is 14 (which is 3rd element of X). Similarly, next element of Y is closest to 15 that is 4th element of X

So, the output I would like should be

```
3
4
4
5
5
```

As my data is large, Can you give me some advice on the systemic/proper code for doing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This is not a code-swapping site, so in general questions like "can you give me the code to do...." are likely to irritate a lot of users.  Instead - post what you've tried, or which dataframe R documentation you've looked at and why it didn't work for you / what you can't understand.  If you hit error messages, post them too.  If you haven't already - read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that's a good starting point to get the best help from the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this piece of code:

```
apply(abs(outer(d$X,d$Y,FUN = '-')),2,which.min)
# [1] 3 4 4 5 5
```

Here, `abs(outer(d$X,d$Y,FUN = '-'))` returns a matrix of unsigned differences between `d$X` and `d$Y`, and `apply(...,2,which.min)` will return position of the minimum by row.