# Find closest value between vectors in data frame by group

Tags: r

I have a dataset `df`:

```r
df <- tibble(
  id = sort(rep(letters[1:3], 3)),
  visit_id = rep(c(0, 5, 10), 3),
  true_visit = c(NA, 3, NA, 0, 5, 10, 1, 7, NA)
)
> df
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  id    visit_id true_visit
  <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 a            0         NA
2 a            5          3
3 a           10         NA
4 b            0          0
5 b            5          5
6 b           10         10
7 c            0          1
8 c            5          7
9 c           10         NA
```

I’m trying to create a new column `closest_visit` where I find the `true_visit` that is closest to `visit_id` within each individual. The result would look like:

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  id    visit_id true_visit closest_visit
  <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
1 a            0         NA             3
2 a            5          3             3
3 a           10         NA             3
4 b            0          0             0
5 b            5          5             5
6 b           10         10            10
7 c            0          1             1
8 c            5          7             7
9 c           10         NA             7
```

To clarify, `closest_visit` is 3 for individual `a` because it's the only `true_visit`. `closest_visit` is 1 for the seventh row because 0 (the `visit_id` for that row) is closer to 1 than it is to 7 (the `true_visit`s for that participant), and so on.

I tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367939/return-value-based-on-finding-closest-value-between-other-two-columns-in-df), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496276/return-rows-establishing-a-closest-value-to-in-r), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437100/searching-the-closest-value-in-other-column). They were a good start but not exactly what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is the `closest_visit` for the seventh row 1? Also, why are there 3 `closest_visit` values per `id b`?

Comment: `rep(letters[1:3], each = 3)` avoids `sort`.

Comment: @tmfmnk for the seventh row (id `c`), `abs(0 - c(1,7)) = c(1, 7)`, the smallest of which is `1`, which corresponds to `true_visit == 1`. For id `b`, each of their true visits matches a different visit ID, so for example `abs(5 - c(0,5,10)) = c(5, 0, 5)`, the smallest of which is `0`, which corresponds to `true_visit == 5`. Does that make sense/answer your question?

Comment: Not really. Isn't it about finding one closest value per ID? Also, why is there a 7 for the ninth row?

Comment: There's a 7 in the ninth row because 10 (the visit id for that row) is closer to 7 than it is to 1 (the true visits for that individual)

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(closest_visit = na.omit(true_visit)[findInterval(true_visit, visit_id)]) %>% fill(closest_visit, .direction = "updown")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could go for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    closest_visit = case_when(
      visit_id == true_visit ~ true_visit,
      TRUE ~ true_visit[sapply(visit_id, 
                               function(x) which.min(abs(x - true_visit)))]
      )
    )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    visit_id true_visit closest_visit
  <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
1 a            0         NA             3
2 a            5          3             3
3 a           10         NA             3
4 b            0          0             0
5 b            5          5             5
6 b           10         10            10
7 c            0          1             1
8 c            5          7             7
9 c           10         NA             7
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is `findInterval` and then `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(closest_visit = na.omit(true_visit)[findInterval(true_visit, 
          visit_id)]) %>% 
   fill(closest_visit, .direction = "updown")
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
#  id    visit_id true_visit closest_visit
#  <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
#1 a            0         NA             3
#2 a            5          3             3
#3 a           10         NA             3
#4 b            0          0             0
#5 b            5          5             5
#6 b           10         10            10
#7 c            0          1             1
#8 c            5          7             7
#9 c           10         NA             7
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind telling me what version of tidyr you are using? I'm using tidyr version 0.8.3 and the only options for `.direction` are `c("up", "down")`.

Comment: @FelixT.  I used `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.3’
> packageVersion('tidyr')
[1] ‘1.0.0’`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most pretty way, but it works on your example:

```
library(dplyr)

for (id in unique(df$id) ) {

  available_visit = na.omit(df[df$id == id ,'true_visit']) %>% pull()
  unique_id = unique(df$visit_id[df$id == id])

    for (visit_id in unique_id) {

      df[df$id == id & df$visit_id ==  visit_id, 'closest_visit' ] <- 
        available_visit[which.min(abs(available_visit-visit_id))]
      }
  }
```